# How to implement PBAP on android

Tags: android, bluetooth

I'm trying to implement PBAP in android, I want to connect to a paired device and extract the phonebook.

Searching in the android repository I see it have classes for this work, but I can't instantiate it.

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/opt/bluetooth/+/master/src/android/bluetooth/client/pbap/BluetoothPbapClient.java

Anyone have a sample code to see how to work with pbap or know how to create an instance of this android classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to look sample in [github](https://github.com/gitzxon/MyBluetoothDemo).

> Getting the phone book from another phone via bluetooth with the PBAP(PhoneBookAccessProfile).