# Accessing contacts using bluetooth

Tags: android, ios, windows-phone-8, bluetooth

I am a Linux, C++ developer. Never worked upon android or iOS. Currently trying to understand android.

I had some sort of awareness of Bluetooth and it's profiles PBAP, MAP, A2DP. However, never done code for the same. So, my question is if a X paired  phone (which may be android / windows / iPhone) with another Y phone (which is suppose a android one ). So Can I access contacts of X phone using Y through PBAP? And How?

Additional questions are, If I connected with paired phone second time, is there any way Y know X phone contacts are changed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To access contacts of phone X from Phone Y, Y would have to implement the PBAP Client role. See [How to implement PBAP on android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36349882/how-to-implement-pbap-on-android)

To know if the contacts on X have changed since the last connection, [PBAP v1.2](https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/adopted-specifications) has a folder version counter that is incremented when a vcard is updated or deleted.